# Can we dynamically populate sitecore multilist field using sitecore queries?

Tags: fieldtype

Can we dynamically manage the left and right-hand side of a Sitecore multilist field using queries? I want top 6 articles (sort based on published date desc) always pop up dynamically on the multilist right-hand side whereas we have all the articles list on the left-hand side of the multilist.

Comment: Are you sure you want them to populated on RHS or you should rather change the code of your component to include the latest 6 articles?

Comment: yes @MarekMusielak , I am creating a website without coding. Do you know any way we could dynamically populate the left and the right hand side of the multilist field.

Comment: @NitiChauhan with out-of box feature, left hand side you can try with the fast query in "Source" of the field in the template builder, but that won't allow you to write the query with sorting.. But can check if Updated field can be used, something like this, query:/sitecore/content/multilist-items/*[@__Updated > '20190514T000000'] But definitely without any coding or customization in sitecore modules, you may not able to achieve what you are looking for..

Comment: @Gobinath can I get the query to sort left hand side of multilist based on Updated date desc.

Comment: @NitiChauhan as I said you can't apply sorting query in multi-list field's source..